# Is it true that $\left(\int |xf(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2} \leq C \left(\int (x^2+1) |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

This is probably true. I'd like to know why it is true. Can we find the value of $C$?

$$\left(\int |xf(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2} \leq C \left(\int (x^2+1) |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: Replace $f$ by $\lambda f$ with $\lambda >0$ then the order of $\lambda$ in RHS is $\lambda$ and in LHS is $2$. Letting $\lambda \to infty$, we see the inequality does not hold.

Comment: @nguyen0610 A very good point to consider. It's also not homogeneous in the measure, so it's even more false.

Comment: Since scaling $f$ is equivalent to scaling the measure, these are just the same false.

Comment: On the other hand, $$ \left(\int |xf(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2} \leq  \left(\int (x^2+1) |f(x)|^2dx\right) $$ is correct just from pointwise estimates.